# Java warns that a casting is unchecked for generics hierarchy

Tags: java, generics, class-hierarchy

If I define the following types for a class:

```
class SomeClass<A extends InterfaceA, B extends InterfaceB, C extends B>
```

While `InterfaceB` extends `InterfaceA`. B also extends A but there I can’t declare that.

When casting an object of type `C` to any of [ `B`, `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB` ], there isn't any warning (as expected).

But when casting `C` to `A` an unchecked cast warning raises. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because A is not in C's inheritance chain.

```
 InterfaceA
 /        \
A      InterfaceB
       /
      B
     /
    C
```

Comment: obviously, I was so into this issue that I didn't notice. My real problem is that I can't do something like that: `C extends B&A`. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Because C extends B, which implements InterfaceB, which in turn extends InterfaceA. C doesn't extend A.